# what does it mean the objectification of something?

Tags: idealism

For example:

```
objectifications of self-consciousness
objectifications of Will
```

What does objetification means?

Specially "objectification of Will" according to Schopenhauer.

The Will becomes an object? How does that make sense?

Comment: Means nothing really. Everything is already an object. I guess a generous interpretation would be, to objectify the will is to think of the will in a way more similar to other objects, instead of elevating it to some special exceptional status.

Comment: See [Objectification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectification): "In Marxism, the objectification of social relationships is discussed as "reification"."

Comment: And see [Schopenhauer's The Objectification of the Will](https://www.marxists.org/reference/subject/philosophy/works/ge/schopenh.htm).